# Is this GetEnumAsStrings<T>() method reinventing the wheel?

Tags: c#, list, foreach, ienumerable, enums

I have a number of **enums** and need to get them as **`List<string>`** objects in order to **enumerate** through them and hence made the `GetEnumAsStrings<T>()` method.

But it seems to me there would be an easier way.

**Is there not a built-in method to get an enum like this into a `List<string>`?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestEnumForeach2312
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> testModes = StringHelpers.GetEnumAsStrings<TestModes>();
            testModes.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class StringHelpers
    {
        public static List<string> GetEnumAsStrings<T>()
        {
            List<string> enumNames = new List<string>();
            foreach (T item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestModes)))
            {
                enumNames.Add(item.ToString());
            }
            return enumNames;
        }
    }

    public enum TestModes
    {
        Test,
        Show,
        Wait,
        Stop
    }
}
```

## Addendum:

Thanks everyone, very insightful. Since I ultimately needed this for **Silverlight** which doesn't seem to have `GetValues()` or `GetNames()` for enums, I made this method which I created from [this method](http://www.dolittle.com/blogs/einar/archive/2008/01/13/missing-enum-getvalues-when-doing-silverlight-for-instance.aspx):

```
public static List<string> ConvertEnumToListOfStrings<T>()
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    var fields = from field in enumType.GetFields()
                 where field.IsLiteral
                 select field;
    foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
        object value = field.GetValue(enumType);
        strings.Add(((T)value).ToString());
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do it as a one-liner using LINQ:

```
var enums = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TestModes)).ToList();
```

Now, keep in mind that [`GetNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx) returns an array of strings... so you might not even need `ToList()`.

**Edit:**
There are ways to improve on your edited code. Here's a simple one that uses `ToList` rather than explicitly instantiating the list:

```
public static List<string> ConvertEnumToListOfStrings<T>()
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);
    var fields = from field in enumType.GetFields()
                 where field.IsLiteral
                 select ((T)field.GetValue(enumType)).ToString();
    return fields.ToList();    
}
```

And this next one is my personal preference. Why instantiate a list at all? You *probably* just need to iterate over the names, not add or remove them from a list. So just use `IEnumerable` and don't bother building the list at all. Saves you one (admittedly small) iteration and the memory overhead of another object.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetEnumNames<T>()
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);
    var fields = from field in enumType.GetFields()
                 where field.IsLiteral
                 select ((T)field.GetValue(enumType)).ToString();
    return fields;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

[MSDN - Enum.GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx)

So for your example it would be:

```
List<string> testModes = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TestModes)).ToList();
```

Or, if you're still back in .NET 2.0

```
List<string> testModes = new List<string>(Enum.GetNames(typeof(TestModes)));
```

If you really need it as a `List<string>`, otherwise I would just work directly with the array.